# Inline editing data table. ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, inline-editing

does anyone know where to find an article or described examples how to make inline editable data table in asp.net core mvc project?

So basically, I just need to do that table with "add", "edit", "delete" buttons, but when you hit them there is no different view appears and that row became editable (like this [example](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DataGrid/RowEditingAndEditingEvents/Angular/Light/) ). I found some similar articles but not for asp.net core mvc.

Thanks for answers in advance.

Comment: Asp.net core is mentioned here, https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DataGrid/RowEditingAndEditingEvents/NetCore/Light/

Comment: Also,you could use jqGrid which is free.Here is a working demo:http://trirandcore.azurewebsites.net/grid/editrowinlineactionicons.